# How to properly set up a Grails update controller to avoid null pointer exception?

Tags: angularjs, grails

My Grails domain class is exactly what you'd expect, just variables with some nullable and others not.

Here is my controller file:

> package 
>   server
>   import grails.converters.JSON
>   class TodoListController {
>
> ```
> def addItem() {
>     def newItem = new Item(request.JSON)
>     newItem.save(flush: true)
>     render newItem as JSON
> }
>
> def index(){
>     render Item.list() as JSON
> }
>
> def updateList() {
>     def newItem = Item.findById(request.JSON.id)
>     newItem.name = request.JSON.name
>     newItem.type = request.JSON.type
>     newItem.priority = request.JSON.priority
>     newItem.completed = request.JSON.completed
>     newItem.comments = request.JSON.comments
>     newItem.creator = request.JSON.creator
>     newItem.assignedTo = request.JSON.assignedTo
>     newItem.save(flush: true)
>     render newItem as JSON
> } }
> ```

And my Angular script:

```
/*------------------------------------------------->
<!-------------------TO DO LIST JS----------------->
<!-------------------------------------------------*/

angular.module('todoApp', ['ngResource'])       // Module for todolist
.controller('todoList', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource) {
        var serverList = $resource('http://localhost:8080/server/todoList/:command');   // Allow commands to be sent to grails app

    $scope.items = serverList.query({command: 'index'});

        $scope.usernames = [];

    $scope.thing = "";  // Entering task default entry

        $scope.priorityOptions =        // List of priority options, name is used for listing options, id for priority color/sort
                [{label: "Top Priority", id: 1},
                 {label: "Mid Priority", id: 2},
                 {label: "Low Priority", id: 3}];

        $scope.worktypeOptions = // Different types of work options
                [{label: "Work", id:1},
                 {label: "Personal", id:2}];

        $scope.addusername = function(){
                $scope.usernames.push($scope.username);
        };

        $scope.ToDoView = function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
            if(($scope.items[i].creator != $scope.username) && ($scope.items[i].assignedTo != $scope.username)) {
                $scope.items.splice(i, 1);
                $scope.ToDoView();
                break;
            }
        }
        };

    $scope.add = function(){    // Function used to add a value to list. Value has name, type, and priority.
                if($scope.thing){      
                        $scope.items.push(
                                {name: $scope.thing,
                                 type: $scope.worktypeSelection,
                                 priority: $scope.prioritySelection,
                                 completed: false,
                                 comments: '',
                                 creator: $scope.username,
                                 assignedTo: $scope.assign
                        });
                        $scope.thing = '';
            $scope.items[$scope.items.length - 1] = serverList.save({command: 'addItem'}, $scope.items[$scope.items.length - 1]);
                }
                else{
                        alert("Empty task is not allowed!");
                }
        };


        $scope.updateList = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
            serverList.save({command: 'updateList'}, item);
        });
    };

    $scope.clear_all = function(){      // Sets "item" array to empty; deletes all.
        $scope.items = [];
    };

        $scope.clear_selected = function(){
                var itemstmp = $scope.items;    // Keep items
                $scope.items = [];      // Clear list
                angular.forEach(itemstmp, function(itemName){
                        if(!itemName.completed){
                                $scope.items.push(itemName);   
                        }
                });
        };
}]);
```

Right now my HTML is set up such that whenever a new item in the list is added by the user, the add function in the JS is called, which should call the addItem controller in my groovy file. I am unsure if this works properly or not.

Then, it should update the server's JSON list when the user clicks the "Save List" button. The problem here is that I get a Null Pointer Exception from Grails, because "name can not be defined for null object". I understand what's happening here (there's no object being detected to be updated), but I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the relevant parts of your code inline in the question itself, not just as pastebin links. Stack Overflow questions need to be self-contained, and not dependent on external links that may go away.

Comment: Just a side note: I'd use `Item.get(request.JSON.id)`.

Comment: Would I use that in place of the entire updatelist function?